# How to remove some Number between two Slash in notepad++

Tags: notepad++, slash

I have Document like this, and I need to remove number between /  / in notepad++

```html
    /554301/5e687cfh36825344e915e
  /557040/756dj4405g376c0dd3c2f
  /567600/287650cf27sdc77d5c73a
  /566270/1fefd5w12345l89aa776d
  /581080/09742m02568n481669da4
  /629500/e4fa1234567aejhtre81a
```

To this:

```html
5e687cfh36825344e915e
756dj4405g376c0dd3c2f
287650cf27sdc77d5c73a
1fefd5w12345l89aa776d
09742m02568n481669da4
e4fa1234567aejhtre81a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If notepad++ supports find&replace with regex, you can find `/\d+/` and replace it with  (nothing).

Answer (score 1):

Notepad++ supports [Regular Expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) so you can use that.

Follow these steps,

1. Press `CTRL+F` in your Notepad++ window.
2. Go to `Replace` tab.
3. At the bottom, select `Regular Expression`.
4. in `Find What` field, type `/\d+/` and leave the `Replace With` field empty.
5. Click on `Replace All`.